# Subset stable IDs based on the largest integer value after the decimal point

Tags: r, string, dataframe, dplyr, filtering

I have a dataframe of old ensembl stable transcript IDs that I am in the process of mapping to current genes. Ensembl stable transcript IDs are a combination of characters and integers. As new information comes out they may choose to update the version number, which is the number after the decimal. I want to subset this dataframe further so that it only includes the most recent (largest) version number.

#### Here is some example data:

| stableID | release |
| --- | --- |
| ENSMUST00000080572.10 | 80 |
| ENSMUST00000080572.11 | 81 |
| ENSMUST00000080572.12 | 82 |
| ENSMUST00000071062.6 | 80 |
| ENSMUST00000071062.7 | 81 |
| ENSMUST00000071062.8 | 82 |
| ENSMUST00000124232.1 | 62 |
| ENSMUST00000124232.1 | 64 |

#### Here is what I would like to return through some code:

| stableID | release |
| --- | --- |
| ENSMUST00000080572.12 | 82 |
| ENSMUST00000071062.8 | 82 |
| ENSMUST00000124232.1 | 62 |
| ENSMUST00000124232.1 | 64 |

I haven't the slightest clue of what to write for this. Current thought is to split the decimal into a third column and then some `dplyr::group_by() %>% dplyr::filter()` shenanigans perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide the `stableID` column into two to divide the ID and version number information. For each `ID` keep rows that have max version number and combine ID and version number information again using `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(stableID, c('ID', 'version_num'), sep = '\\.', convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(version_num == max(version_num)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  unite(stableID, ID, version_num, sep = '.')

# stableID              release
#  <chr>                   <int>
#1 ENSMUST00000080572.12      82
#2 ENSMUST00000071062.8       82
#3 ENSMUST00000124232.1       62
#4 ENSMUST00000124232.1       64
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(stableID = c("ENSMUST00000080572.10", "ENSMUST00000080572.11", 
"ENSMUST00000080572.12", "ENSMUST00000071062.6", "ENSMUST00000071062.7", 
"ENSMUST00000071062.8", "ENSMUST00000124232.1", "ENSMUST00000124232.1"
), release = c(80L, 81L, 82L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 62L, 64L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R` with `ave` and `transform`.  Read the 'stableID' column with `read.table` into two column, `subset` the rows based on the `max` value of 'V2'

```
subset(transform(read.table(text = df$stableID, sep=".", header = FALSE), 
    release = df$release), ave(V2, V1, FUN = max) == V2)
                  V1 V2 release
3 ENSMUST00000080572 12      82
6 ENSMUST00000071062  8      82
7 ENSMUST00000124232  1      62
8 ENSMUST00000124232  1      64
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(stableID = c("ENSMUST00000080572.10", "ENSMUST00000080572.11", 
"ENSMUST00000080572.12", "ENSMUST00000071062.6", "ENSMUST00000071062.7", 
"ENSMUST00000071062.8", "ENSMUST00000124232.1", "ENSMUST00000124232.1"
), release = c(80L, 81L, 82L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 62L, 64L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
    df,
    !!ave(
        as.numeric(gsub(".*\\.", "", stableID)),
        gsub("\\..*", "", stableID),
        FUN = function(x) x == max(x)
    )
)
```

gives

```
               stableID release
3 ENSMUST00000080572.12      82
6  ENSMUST00000071062.8      82
7  ENSMUST00000124232.1      62
8  ENSMUST00000124232.1      64
```